# Reuse Testconfigurations from VS 2008 in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, automated-tests

I'm currently investigating my options to run automated tests from within Visual Studio 2008 Professional. I noticed that the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182469%28v=vs.90%29) documenting the integrated funcionality is only available for VS 2008 and VS 2005. This kind of makes me suspcious. Since we are planning to upgrade to VS 2010 I'm wondering whether I will able to continue to use my configurations and knowledge with VS 2010? Does anyone here have made any experience with this?

TIA, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to be nervous, the terminology around the test configuration has merely changed in VS 2010. Most of what you know is the same but resides under different product branding which causes some versioning problems in the documentation.

Most notably, "test configuration" is often referred to as "[test settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx)" under 2010.

Microsoft moved away from silo-ed "Team Test" terminology of VS 2005/2008 to a more holistic big picture known as *Microsoft Application Lifetime Management*, where testing is an integrated component for delivery of successful applications.  Keep in mind that most of the documentation you'll find for testing refers to the Test Manager, which ship with the Ultimate and Test editions of Visual Studio. The Test Manager ties Tests to Use Cases and Requirements and is part of that big picture.

If you're not going down the ALM big picture, the focused view of just running tests hasn't changed much at all, with the exception of some new features like *Test Impact* which are pretty cool.

The following links may be useful to you, as it sounds like you're interested in how the tests can be used by developers or part of your build process:

- [Running Automated Tests within Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182470)
- [Running Automated Tests from the Command-line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487)

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is comforting news. Thank you.